# NestJS - Passport and Strategies error Authentication strategies must have a name

Tags: jwt, nestjs, nestjs-passport

Rookie to NestJS, i try to implement Passport, when i build the app, got :

Authentication strategies must have a name

In the auth.module :

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        UserModule,
        PassportModule.register({
            defaultStrategy: 'jwt',
            property: 'user',
            session: false,
        }),
        JwtModule.register({
            secret: process.env.SECRET,
            signOptions: {
                expiresIn: process.env.EXPIRESIN
            }
        })
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        JwtStrategy
    ],
    ...
    })
```

The Strategy (JwtStrategy class) looks like :

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(
        private readonly authService: AuthService
    ) {
        super(
            {
                jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
                secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET
            }
        )
    }

    public async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<any> {
        return null;
    }
}
```

After hours, i didn't find any response... Sure i'm missing something, but don't know what.

Thx for your answers...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad... I just realized that i'd two strategies in different packages...